# I need to add a column to my df that has the count of certain keywords of the articles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-mining

This is my dataframe.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnfQu.png)

All I need is to aggregate a new column that contain how many times the keyword "protesta" appear in the article.

I never have done text mining in python so please I'd be very grateful if someone helps me.

this is my code:

```
root = 'https://www.google.com/'
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#

rows = []

link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=revuelta+EMOL&rlz=1C1UEAD_esCL995CL995&biw=1536&bih=714&tbm=nws&ei=gYyLYsrmLvKc5OUP3Ji-mAg&ved=0ahUKEwiKq9zF3fX3AhVyDrkGHVyMD4MQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=revuelta+EMOL&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LW5ld3MQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToGCAAQHhAWOgoIABAeEA8QFhAKOggIABAeEA8QFjoFCAAQgAQ6CAghEB4QFhAdULkGWOEQYKgSaABwAHgAgAFkiAHXBJIBAzkuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-news'
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

req = Request(link, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#

requests.get(link, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

webpage = urlopen(req).read()
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

with requests.Session() as c:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')
    for item in soup.find_all('div', attrs= {'class': 'ZINbbc luh4tb xpd O9g5cc uUPGi'}):
        raw_link = item.find('a', href=True)['href']
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#
        
        link = raw_link.split('/url?q=')[1].split('&sa=U&')[0]
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#
        
        article = Article(link, language = "es")
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#
        
        article.download()
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 5)) #----------stop---------#
        
        article.parse()
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 5)) #----------stop---------#
        
        title = article.title
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#
        
        descript = article.text
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#
        
        date = article.publish_date
        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#
        
        rows.append([link, title, date, descript])
        
        
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["link", "title", "date", "article"])
df_1
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string method `str.count()` that counts how many times a substring appears within a string.

```
df['word_count'] = df['article'].str.count('protesta')
```